# What is the minimal distance of clearance in the direction of flight path for a rocket?

Tags: launch, rockets, safety

Usually the rocket launch sites are placed on a coast or a place where there's basically no civilian buildings in the direction of flight path.

Is there a standard/regulation on the minimal clearance?

Comment: families living under the flightpath from Woomera were built shelters they were supposed to go into when there was a launch.

Comment: ...some villages in Kazakhstan live off selling titanium and aluminum junk that falls off the sky...